# How to send parameters in the method onStart with ROSJava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In every example in the **ROSJava** tutorial, the method: **onStart** has a unique parameter: **(final Node node)** and my question is how to send additional parameters in this method.

When I execute any node, I type in the shell:

```
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py nxt_lejos_ros org.lejos.ros.nodes.loader.NXTLoader __name:=NXTLoader
```

or I use a **.launch** file with the following structure:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="rosjava_bootstrap" 
    type="run.py" 
    args="nxt_lejos_ros org.lejos.ros.nodes.loader.NXTLoader" 
    name="NXTLoader" 
    output="screen" />     
</launch>
```

But my idea, is to send to the node another parameter, for example a **YAML** file.

How to define in a .launch code an aditional parameter and how to modify the signature of the **onStart** method?

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12643/how-to-send-parameters-in-the-method-onstart-with-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I work with NXT and LeJos too.
I send parameters to node using the parameter server.
I wrote file robot.yaml

```
parameter_namespace: nxt_robot
nxt_robot:
  list: [motorA,sonarIn4]
  setttings:
    motorA:
      type: motor
      name: radar_motor
      port: 1.0
      frame_id: radar_motor_link
      desired_frequency: 50.0
    sonarIn4:
      type: ultrasonic
      frame_id: ultrasonic_link
      name: ultrasonic_sensor
      port: 4.0
      desired_frequency: 50.0
```

and load it in launch-file

```
<launch>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find nxt_rosjava)/robot.yaml" />
  <node pkg="rosjava_bootstrap" 
    type="run.py" 
    args="nxt_rosjava org.ros.nxt_rosjava.Listener" 
    name="nxt_rosjava" 
    output="screen" />  
</launch>
```

In class Listener I load parameters.

```
  ParameterTree param = node.newParameterTree();
  GraphName paramNamespace = new GraphName(param.getString("parameter_namespace"));
  NameResolver resolver = node.getResolver().newChild(paramNamespace);
  Map setttings_map = param.getMap(resolver.resolve("setttings"));
  Object[] list = param.getList(resolver.resolve("list")).toArray();
  lst_devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
      String type = (String) ((Map) setttings_map.get(list[i])).get("type");
      String name_dev = (String) ((Map) setttings_map.get(list[i])).get("name");
      String frame_id = (String) ((Map) setttings_map.get(list[i])).get("frame_id");
      double tmp_port = (Double) ((Map) setttings_map.get(list[i])).get("port");
      int port = (int) tmp_port;
      double desired_frequency = (Double) ((Map) setttings_map.get(list[i])).get("desired_frequency");
      log.info("Device: " + list[i] + " type: " + type + " frequency: "+desired_frequency);
      if (type.contains("ultrasonic")){
          UltraSonicSensorNXT dev = new UltraSonicSensorNXT(port, desired_frequency, node, name_dev, frame_id);
          lst_devices.add(dev);  
      }
      if (type.contains("motor")){
          MotorNXT dev = new MotorNXT(port, (int)desired_frequency, node, name_dev);
          lst_devices.add(dev);  
      }
      if (type.contains("touch")){
          TouchSensorNXT dev = new TouchSensorNXT(port, (int)desired_frequency, node, name_dev, frame_id);
          lst_devices.add(dev);  
      }
  }
```

[My current code](http://code.google.com/p/lego-nxt-car-like/)

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-12**:
Hi Alexander, many thanks for your idea. I will test this week to add in the new stack that we are doing in LeJOS project. http://lejos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lejos/trunk/ros/ I was surfing in your googlecode project and what is the idea about nxt_steering_control? Cheers

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-12**:
I am going to use nxt_steering_control for connect top-level ROS nodes and rosjava node which control Lego NXT. For example, script nxt_steering_control.py listen pilot\drive (http://www.ros.org/wiki/art_pilot) and send command to topic "joint_command" rosjava node.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-12**:
All scripts in stack  nxt_steering_control  are specific for my robot Lego NXT car-like. Project is not finished yet. This is photo my robot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/1s1ih

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi, today I tested your idea, but I have a problem with this line:    GraphName paramNamespace = new GraphName(param.getString("parameter_namespace"));
NameResolver resolver = node.getResolver().newChild(paramNamespace);

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi, today I tested your idea, but I have a problem with this line:

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi, today I tested your idea, but I have a problem with this line:        GraphName paramNamespace = new GraphName(param.getString("parameter_namespace"));
NameResolver resolver = node.getResolver().newChild(paramNamespace);

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi, today I tested your idea, but I have a problem with this line:

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-26**:
HI, I tested your idea, but I have a problem with this line:  NameResolver resolver = node.getResolver().newChild(paramNamespace); the method newChild doesn't exist. Any alternative?

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-26**:
Hi! I haven't got this error. There is method "newChild" in file "rosjava_core/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/namespace/NameResolver.java". May be I or you used old version rosjava?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically parameters are specified using the parameter server. There is currently no support for command line parameters in rosjava.

See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Parameter%20Server and http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/node/Node.java#212

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1